# Location of postgresql database in nitrous.io project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, devise, nitrousio

I'm not sure if I'm going mad or if Heroku's dataclips are acting up but I have the following problem.

I've set up a ruby on rails development environment on Nitrous.io and have connected to a database on Heroku. In Nitrous.io I then type `psql`to access postgresql.

From there I type `\l`to list the databases.

Then `\c <name of development database hosted on heroku>`

Then `\dt` to list the relations, one of which is `users`

Finally, I input the command `SELECT * FROM users;` and this returns relevant information on users such as email address, encrypted password etc etc.

However, when I go to Heroku and create a dataclip with the code `select * from users`to be run against the same database, I'm getting the following warning

```
Error: Dataclip cannot be created
ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 2: select * from users
```

Am I completely missing something here or is the dataclip throwing an error for no reason? I'm using Devise (for the first time) in my app. Would this have anything to do with it?

**Edit**

I'm starting to think I've stored the database on Nitrous.io and not in Heroku. I think I may have used autoparts to install postgresql on my nitrous.io vm

I've run the command `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'` as a dataclip on Heroku and the users table just isn't there. I then ran it on some other projects I have on Heroku and I can clearly see the tables I've created.

Can anyone confirm my suspicion or know how I can check the location of the database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I had indeed set the postgresql database up in nitrous.io itself rather than on Heroku. This page explains it: http://blog.nitrous.io/2013/07/02/building-a-rails-4.0-app-on-nitrous-io.html